# How to enable python scripts on 123-reg shared hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, python

I'm trying to use python for scripting on 123-reg.co.uk and the host has no tutorials available. Does anyone have any examples?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I got it working.

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgitb
import cgi
cgitb.enable()
cgi.test()
```

.htaccess

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

Set execute on test.py by chmod 755